# Where is i2c_master_recv 's value coming from?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I don't understand why i2c_master_send need register's address?

But i2c_master_recv don't need register's address.

Can I receive specific register adress value using i2c_master_recv ?

Where is i2c_master_recv 's value coming from?

Why i2c_master_send the third parameter is 2 but i2c_master_recv  the third parameter is 1?

Below is the sample code for i2c_master_send and i2c_master_recv .

Thank you very much.

```
    struct i2c_client *client
    unsigned char buf[2] = {0};
    int ret;

    buf[0]=0x30;//set register's address
    buf[1]=0x05;//set register's value

    //set register
    ret = i2c_master_send(client, buf, 2);
    if(ret < 0)
        printk(KERN_ERR "Write data failed\n");
    //read register
    ret = i2c_master_recv(client, buf, 1);
    if(ret < 0)
        printk(KERN_ERR "Read data failed\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two addresses the I2C protocol can use: address of a chip on the I2C bus (7 bits or 10 bits), and address of a register. Technically speaking, the address of a register is at a level higher than I2C, so it's not really part of the I2C protocol.

When you send data, all data sent will be from the host. There will be no "response".

When you receive data, all data received will be from the device. There is no "register address".

So, in this case you're essentially wondering how you can read a register by its address. This is device-specific, but will usually work by first telling (send) the device somehow the address you're accessing without its value, and then reading data from the device.

I'm not sure how your particular chip is designed, but if I was the microchip designer, I would support reading from an arbitrary register address by writing only 1 byte (address, no value) and then reading 1 byte (thus returning the value at the address). I would also support writing to an arbitrary register address by writing 2 bytes (address, value).

So, essentially you have to select the register by sending its address, and then you can access the register by receiving its contents.

I'm not sure if your chip is designed this way. You seriously need to take a hard look at the I2C specs of the chip.